# How to make a Canvas look the same for all display sizes

Tags: android, canvas

I'm trying to create a game for Android using Canvas. Everything seemed perfect till now, when I tried to run it on a bigger device. It's simple. The display has more pixels(Points) so logically the game takes place at the left upper corner.

How to fix this? I was thinking about `Display.getSize(...)` and then adapting all components to this size but that's also a problem because I use few PNGs and if I adapt their sizes to another Display format(I mean the size), they will be too thin and it will look weird.

Shall I use something else than a Canvas? Please help me.

Comment: Try drawing relative to the actual screen size. context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics() has 2 public variables, widthPixels/heightPixels, that you can use to get the actual display size in pixels and draw accordingly.

Comment: but what to do with the png sprites? It's not a problem to change their size but... FOR INSTANCE if we have a display that has the size 5x4 and the second one has 7x5 ...?

Comment: it would look strange

Comment: You should be resizing them according to the dimensions as well (ie. using percentage variations and not hardcoded values), otherwise you're going to get the same bordered box you're getting by using hardcoded dimensions. And keep in mind, there are so many different device sizes and aspect ratios that it's not physically possible for it to look "the same" on all devices. The closest you can get is using dimension percentages when drawing everything.

Comment: thank you. I was thinking about doing it this way but I thought there must be some other way. Now I see it's not really possible to do it differently